# Spark-scala: Converting dataframe to mllib Matrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to transpose a huge dataframe (100Mx20K). As the dataframe is spread over multiple nodes and difficult to collect on the driver, I would like to do the transpose through conversion through `mllib` matrices. The idea seems to have been tested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184319/convert-dataframe-into-spark-mllib-matrix-in-scala), so the opted procedure was as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix}

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("temp/test.parquet").select("H1","H2","H3","H4")
val matrixColumns = df.columns

val rdd = df.select(array(matrixColumns:_*).as("arr")).as[Array[Int]].rdd
  .zipWithIndex()
  .map{ case(arr, index) => IndexedRow(index, Vectors.dense(arr.map(_.toDouble)))} 

val dm = new IndexedRowMatrix(rdd).toBlockMatrix().toLocalMatrix()
```

I noticed a possible type and tried substitution:

```
orig:
    val rdd = df.select(array(matrixColumns:_*).as("arr"))....

modified:
    val rdd = df.select(Array(matrixColumns:_*)).as("arr")...
```

However, neither works for me and the above change throws error:

```
scala> df.select(Array(matrixColumns:_*)).as("arr")
              ^
       error: overloaded method select with alternatives:
         [U1](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1]): org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U1] <and>
         (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
         (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
        cannot be applied to (Array[String])
```

I am unsure if there is a version issue (I am using Spark 3.3.0) or if the problem is elsewhere. I would be grateful for any help in fixing the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the select invocation to:

```
df.select(matrixColumns.head, matrixColumns: _*)
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

df.select(matrixColumns.map(col(_)):_*)
```

Comment: While the modified approach worked, the performance was terrible and crashed after an hour even for a relatively smaller data. I have to find some other way of doing the operation. Among what I could succeed, for data that fits into RAM, `Polars` (in Python) seems to be the best solution.

Comment: That matrix is enormous, I suppose that your matrix is sparse, isn´t it?, Work with Sparse vectors in that case.

Comment: No, totally dense. 4x1M was the test data. I am trying now to collect columns one at a time, write a CSV (or something like that) and read again. Not sure if it will be able to load so many columns though.

Comment: Try to use Block Matrix: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/BlockMatrix.html